# Golang nested, renamed XML attributes

Tags: xml, go

Given the following struct:

```
type book struct {
    XMLName xml.Name   `xml:"DailyAct"`
    Symbol     string  `xml:"TradeInstrId,attr"`
    EntityId   string  `xml:"EntityId,attr"`
    AssetClass string  `xml:"AssetClass,attr"`
    Open       int     `xml:"Open"`
    High       int     `xml:"High"`
    Low        int     `xml:"Low"`
    Close      int     `xml:"Close"`
    // Type      string `` //I'll leave this for another question
}
```

My current XML:

```
  <DailyAct EntityId="foo" AssetClass="bar" TradeInstrId="Symbol" >
      <Open>2</Open>
      <High>3</High>
      <Low>1</Low>
      <Close>5</Close>
  </DailyAct>
```

But, I need to repurpose certain fields of the struct (or generate xml another way) to achieve:

```
<DailyAct EntityId="foo" AssetClass="bar" TradeInstrId="Symbol">
  <Open Price="2" Type="IND"/>
  <High Price="6" Type="IND"/>
  <Low Price="1" Type="IND"/>
  <Close Price="4" Type="IND"/>
</DailyAct>
```

But I get: `&errors.errorString{s:"xml: DailyAct>Open chain not valid with Price,attr flag"} (actual)` when I try to nest fields like so:

```
type book struct {
    //...
    Open       int     `xml:"DailyAct>Open,Price,attr>"`
    //...
}
```

**Edit:** 
I found this [discussion](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3688), while googling around so what I'm going for may not be feasible currently

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right currently it's impossible. But you can use sub-structures like

```
type PriceType struct {
    Price int    `xml:"Price,attr"`
    Type  string `xml:"Type,attr"`
}

type Book struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name  `xml:"DailyAct"`
    Symbol     string    `xml:"TradeInstrId,attr"`
    EntityId   string    `xml:"EntityId,attr"`
    AssetClass string    `xml:"AssetClass,attr"`
    Open       PriceType `xml:"Open"`
    High       PriceType `xml:"High"`
    Low        PriceType `xml:"Low"`
    Close      PriceType `xml:"Close"`
}
```

Example here http://play.golang.org/p/Ekd6Xf3miS